# Término para una tendencia o afición

Tags: solicitud-de-término, sustantivos

Estoy aquí tratando de recordar una palabra, ¿tal vez me ayudan?

Doy un ejemplo: salió la bicicleta plegable.  En vista de un éxito inicial, se empezaron a producir artículos relacionados con la bicicleta plegable: el estuche, la maleta, los accesorios, etc., y entonces continúan con una gran línea de productos para la bicicleta plegable.

La palabra que quiero saber se refiere a todo este conjunto de cosas, la bicicleta con sus posibles accesorios junto a la afición de la persona.

Esta palabra sí existe, la escuché justo con este tema de las bicicletas plegables: el vendedor me mostró la bicicleta, y después me mostró todos los accesorios y me dijo: "eso de la bicicleta plegable ahora es todo un(a) ... , que el morral, que el gancho, que el soporte...".

Comment: Tal vez: *toda una maraña*.

Answer (score 2):

Creo que la palabra que buscas es **parafernalia**

La definición de la RAE no le hace plena justicia pero por lo menos dice que se toma del inglés y ahi si la defiicion se adapata a lo que preguntas.

> **paraphernalia** ˌparəfəˈneɪlɪə/ 
>   noun:
>   miscellaneous articles,
>   especially the equipment needed for a particular activity. i.e "drills,
>   saws, and other paraphernalia necessary for home improvements"
>
> synonyms: equipment, stuff, things, apparatus, tackle, kit, implements, tools, utensils, material(s),

La RAE [dice](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RpxkOFc): 
[image]

y la definición de [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraphernalia) lo confirma;

> Paraphernalia most commonly refers to a group of apparatus, equipment,
>   or furnishing used for a particular activity. For example, an avid
>   sports fan may cover his walls with football and/or basketball
>   paraphernalia.

Answer (score 1):

La primera palabra que se me ocurre es bastante común:

> [**moda**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=PTFxq8T)
>
> 1. f. Uso, modo o costumbre que está en boga durante algún tiempo, o en determinado país.
> 2. f. Gusto colectivo y cambiante en lo relativo a prendas de vestir y complementos.
> 3. f. Conjunto de la vestimenta y los adornos de moda.

Se aplica a cualquier nueva tendencia que pega fuerte durante un tiempo: la moda del *running*, la moda del póquer, la moda de los *spinner*...
Cuando el público se cansa de la cosa en cuestión y cambia de afición, se dice que eso está (o se ha) *pasado de moda*.

Como digo, es una palabra bastante común. Algunas personas usan [**novedad**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Qf48Xbb) como sinónimo, quizá fue esa la que escuchaste.